# Reverse-Engineer a material

Tags: experimental-chemistry, materials

Let's say I am seeking to find an alloy with certain properties, is there any method or process that enables one to backtrack from desired properties to actual structure and composition of a material?

Comment: Try [MatWeb](http://www.matweb.com/), where you can search by physical properties, material type, alloy composition, and up to 3 physical/chemical properties (a very extensive list); and [NIST's Material Measurement Laboratory](http://www.nist.gov/mml/), as well as [NIST's Standard Reference Data](http://www.nist.gov/srd/materials.cfm). These can at least get you started with a name of something from which you can look into the structure and composition.

Answer (score 2):

**In general no.**

What you're describing is known as *inverse design,* that is, designing something with particular properties.

I agree completely with the comment above, that you can find many things from databases. But when you mix together multiple components, into new inter-metallic compounds or alloys, the results do not necessarily match the individual components.

Consider, for example, ["Galinstan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galinstan), the various alloys of gallium, indium, and tin. While each of these have low melting points, the eutectic point for the ternary alloy is $\:\mathrm{-19 ^{\circ} C}$.

There are many other examples, but the point remains that without careful experiments or theory for materials design, it's tricky to do inverse design.

Comment: Now if you *really* want to do it anyways, there are multiple experimental or computational strategies to get it done. For metals or inorganic systems, so-called "alchemical DFT" methods let you optimize the atomic number of a system for a particular property.